# how to set background color for disabled dates in calendar

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

hi i want to change background color for disabled dates in calendar.am using wdullaer MaterialDateTimePicker library.can any body please give me an idea how do it.
this is source link 
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/

Comment: why you need a library for that ?

Comment: actually that library has a feature for disabling dates in the calendar@Charuක

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot use [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) library, it's work fine in this case what you only need to do is to write your custom style and set it in the dialog like this:

**STYLES:**

```
<style name="calenderPicker">
    <item name="bpHeaderBackgroundColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="bpPreHeaderBackgroundColor">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="bpHeaderUnselectedTextColor">@color/radial_gray_light</item>
    <item name="bpHeaderSelectedTextColor">@color/bpWhite</item>
    <item name="bpBodyBackgroundColor">@color/bpWhite</item>
    <item name="bpBodySelectedTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="bpBodyUnselectedTextColor">@color/date_picker_text_normal</item>
    <item name="bpButtonsBackgroundColor">@color/bpWhite</item>
    <item name="bpButtonsTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="bpRadialBackgroundColor">@color/radial_gray_light</item>
    <item name="bpRadialTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="bpRadialPointerColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="bpAmPmCircleColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="bpDisabledDayTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item> //DISABLED DAYS
</style>
```

**JAVA:**

```
CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment cdp = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment()
            .setDisabledDays(disabledDays)
            .setThemeCustom(R.style.calenderPicker);
```